# While loop goes on when the condition is false

Tags: c, while-loop

My while loop goes on even when the condition is false. 
What I expected to print is that another pokemon will appear when the user runs away, but instead it prints strings for when the user encountered a pokemon. Does the declaration of the variable 'choice' have anything to do with it ?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <time.h>

int chance();     //Generates percentage for catch
void encounter(); //Randomly spawns pokemons
void catch(int);         //Decides whether the pokemon is captured or not
void restart(); //decides whether to restart the game 
void reset();      //resets all global variables

void playerChoice();

//list of pokemons
char pokemon[5][10] = {"Magikarp", "Zubat", "Eevee", "Magmar", "Pikachu"};
int type[5];
int pokemonType = 0;
int captured = 0, pokeball = 20, metPokemon = 0, capPokemon = 0;


int main() {
    int inGame = 0;
    //if pokeballs != 0 AND not met any pokemon OR captured a pokemon
    while(pokeball != 0 && metPokemon == 0){
        system("cls");
        encounter();
        playerChoice();
    } 

    //DOES NOT CARE ABOUT MEETING POKEMON OR NOT 
    if(pokeball == 0) {
        system("cls");
        printf("You have used up all your pokeballs \n");
    }
    restart();
}

void encounter() {
    int i;

    //random number generator from 0 - 4
    srand(time(NULL));
    i = (rand() % 5);

    //prints out the pokemon name 
    printf("A wild %s appeared!\n", pokemon[i]);
    metPokemon = 1;
    capPokemon = 0;
    pokemonType = i;
}

void playerChoice() {
    int selection;
    int choice = 0;
    while (choice == 0){
        printf("\nWhat will you do?\n");
        printf("1:Throw a pokeball!\n2:Run Away!\n");
        scanf(" %d", &selection);

        if (selection == 1) {
            choice = 1;
            catch(chance());

        } else if (selection == 2) {
            choice = 1;         //choice is 1 but why does it keep asking ? 
            metPokemon = 0;
            printf("\nYou ran away successfully!\n");
            printf("%d\n", metPokemon);
            printf("%d\n", choice);
            system("pause");
        } else {
            printf("Please enter [1] or [2] only!\n");
            choice = 0;
            getchar();
        }
    };
}

int chance() {
    //variable declaration
    int percent;

    //random number generator from 1 - 100
    srand(time(0));
    percent = (rand() % 10) + 1;
    return percent;
}

void catch() {
    //int i = 1;
    //time_t end  = time(NULL) + 3; //7s

    /*spinning animation
    while(i) {
        spinner();
        if(time(NULL) >= end){
        break;
        }
    }
    */

    //if keep breaking free, loop until gotcha 
    if(chance() <5) {
        printf("The pokemon broke free!\n");
        metPokemon = 1;
        capPokemon = 0;
        pokeball -= 1;
        printf("You have %d pokeballs left!\n", pokeball);

        //recursive functions
        while (metPokemon = 1 && capPokemon != 1 && pokeball != 0) {
            playerChoice();
        }

    } else {
        printf("\nGotcha!\n");
        type[pokemonType] += 1;
        capPokemon = 1;
        metPokemon = 0;
        pokeball -= 1;
        captured += 1;
        printf("You have %d pokeballs left! \n\n", pokeball);
        getchar();
        getchar();
    }
}

void restart() {
    int startOver = 0;
    int input;
    do {
        printf("Do you wish to continue playing?\n1:Yes\n2:No\n");
        scanf( " %d", &input); 

        if(input == 1) {
            printf("Restarting the game... \n");
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            startOver = 1;
        } else if (input == 2) {
            printf("See you again next time! \n"); 
            exit(0);
        } else {
            printf("Please enter [1] or [2] only! \n\n");
            startOver = 0;
            getchar();
        }
    }
        while (startOver == 0);
}
```

Comment: The `catch` function looks like this =>> `void catch() {}` and you call it like this `catch(chance());` Do you notice something here?

Comment: Does `srand(time(0))` have anything to do with it? You should call it *once* at the start of the program. But you re-seed the RNG every time you call `rand()`.

Comment: when writing function prototypes for functions that take no parameters, place `void` between the parens otherwise the compiler will generate code to allow any number of parameters in the actual function call.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: this function signature: `void catch() {` does not match the prototype: `void catch( int );` nor the call to the function: `catch(chance());`   Did you actually try to compile the posted code?

Comment: by calling the function: `srand()` repeatedly, (in this case, all in the same second of time) the value returned by the call to `rand()` will always be the same.  Not what you want.  Suggest placing the call at the beginning of the `main()` function, so it is only called once.

Comment: on this line: `while (metPokemon = 1 && capPokemon != 1 && pokeball != 0) {`   the expressiion: `metPokemon = 1` is probably a keypunch error where you actually meant `metPokemon == 1`.   This is the very kind of reason that the literal should be placed on the left, so the compiler will catch this kind of error, rather than you spending many an hour debugging trying to find the error.  I.E. using: `1 = metPokemon` would have resulted in a compiler warning and you would have immediately seen the problem

Comment: the posted code will only run under windows due to the non portable `conio.h` header file, the `system( "pause" )` and similar statement.s.  Also, none of the facilities in the header file `conio.h` are being used.  It is almost always a bad idea to `#include` header files that are not needed.

Comment: regarding the comment:  `//choice is 1 but why does it keep asking ?`  The most likely reason is because the `stdin` file stream contains a newline that has not been consumed before asking for user input.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding this line: `};` in the `while()` loop in the function:  `playerChoice()` there should NOT be a semicolon following the closing brace in the `while()` code block